# MySQLdb connection.close() is not working in Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am using Python 2.7.14. I have the following code.

```
conDB = MySQLdb.connect(self.dbhost, self.dbuser, self.dbpassword, self.dbname)
sqlCur = conDB.cursor()
sqlCur.execute(MYQUERY)
sqlCur.close()
conDB.close()
```

When I run command `show status like '%onn%';` in MySQL, I can see the value of "Connections" variable keep increasing every time the code is executed. Eventually, I get "Too Many Connections" error. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: Don't you have another program (another (modified) instance of your script, or a service) that is running and triggering extra connections?

Comment: @CristiFati No, there is nothing else running. In fact, I tested this on my standalone machine and check the MySQL connection. Every time I run a program, I see connection count increases.